# How to get query string in catch block of MySQL exception in java?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

How can I get SQL query that was received 
by MySQL server when it raises exception?

I have a code similar to the following:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    con = DbConnectionManager.getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    setStatementParameters(ps, params);
    ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLExeption e) {
    // How to get wrong query here?
} finally {
    DbConnectionManager.closeConnection(ps, con);
}
```

Where query variable is like "INSERT into `someTable` (`qwe`, `asd`) VALUES (?, ?)"
The question is how can I get query string in the catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run across another solution to this problem.

The MySQL JDBC driver overrides the toString of PreparedStatement to display the query as it is sent to the database. This is implementation dependent so it may not the best thing to rely on, but it's very simple to get at. I'm now using this to dump query text to a log file for debugging purposes. While there are probably other solutions that are more portable and future-proof, this has the advantage of getting exactly the string that the MySQL driver says it's sending to the database.

The string comes back with an object ID, then a colon, then the SQL string. You can split it on the colon to get just the SQL.

The type com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement also exposes a protected method call asSql(). You could override the class with your own implementation that gives public access to this method. From looking at the disassembly of the class's toString() method, it seems to be using asSql() to get the actual SQL string. This approach adds the problem of how to instantiate your subclass, though; the simplest approach is just to use the toString that you already have access to, without even having to downcast your PreparedStatement to a MySQL-specific subtype.

Again, just be aware that the maintainers of the MySQL API probably don't consider this part of the public interface to their software (JDBC defines the standard interface), so they may make changes later that would break this mechanism. For the time being, though, it will get the job done.

This is true for the version of the MySQL driver I'm currently using, which is 5.1.7.

Answer (score 2):

The SQLException may or may not have the query string contained in its exception message. You can't depend on it. If you just want to see it for debugging purposes, though, then that's probably your best bet. However, in this particular example that's not a problem because you have direct access to the `query` variable that you used to set up the query in the first place.

Comment: query variable doesn't contain final query

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see it with the parameters substituted in?

Comment: That's in a private member variable, you can see it in the debugger but I don't think there's any way to get at it from your code. (Aside from modifying the MySQL JDBC driver source code, which you could do.)